# Number of possibilities to rearrange a word such that a character is to the right of the other

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question:

In how many ways can we arrange the word $FOOTBALL$ in a row such that $A$ will appear to the right of $F$ (but not necessarily coupled).

If I scale down the problem I can see that this condition divides the possibilities in 2. Therefore having $$\frac{8!}{2!*2!*2}$$

Why does this condition divides the number of ways in 2?

Comment: Pair each permutation with the permutation which is the same save that the $F$ and $A$ are switched.

Comment: The probability that A appears right to F is $\frac {1}{2}$

Comment: There is a bijection between the set  where F appears before A and the set where A appears before F, and their union is the full set of arrangements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, there are $\frac{8!}{2! \cdot 2!}$ ways of permutation. Because there is only one instance of $A$ and one instance of $F$, and no two character can be placed in the same position, this leads us to say that because $A$ is either to the left or to the right of $F$ (you could say that vice versa, too) then in exactly half of these permutations the letter $A$ is to the left of the letter $F$, and in the other half the letter $A$ is to the right of letter $F$.

From here all you need to do is divide the total number of permutations by $2$ to get your answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I understand it now. Didn't interpreted this condition like that :)

Answer (score 2):

The given answers already cover your question. But, if you want to solve this problem in a different manner, probably because you find the current answer confusing, here it is:

Fix the two places $F$ and $A$ will occupy in $^8C_2$ ways (since $A$ can only occur to the right of $F$). The remaining letters can be permuted in the remaining places in $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ ways.

So, total ways are $= ^8C_2\frac{6!}{2!2!}=\frac{8!}{6!2!}\frac{6!}{2!2!}=\frac{8!}{2!2!\cdot2}$ .

Comment: hmm great answer! thank you for another perspective on the problem.

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld You're welcome :D

Answer (score 1):

Because if $X$ is a valid arrangement, then swapping F and A in $X$ gives an invalid arrangement, and vice versa.